# ActivityIndicator doesn't stop after computations

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm trying to make activity indicator while uploading files, so i've found a lot of solutions, but i guess i don't fully understand them, so my code look like this:

```
- (void) startSpinner {

UIActivityIndicatorView  *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[spinner setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2.0, self.view.frame.size.height/2.0)];
[self.view addSubview:spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];

}


- (void)startSync {

[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startSpinner) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

// computations 

[self.spinner stopAnimating];
}
```

So after i do [self startSync] activityIndicator appears, but after uploading it didn't stop. Also if i declare activity indicator somewhere else (not in the (void)startSpinner), for example in viewDidLoad, and only do [self startAnimating] it didn't appear at all. Please help me find out errors.

Answer (score 4):

You're performing UI operations on a thread that isn't the main thread.
You should never call `detachNewThreadSelector` with a selector that performs UI related tasks.

A better, more understandable way to do this is:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //Perform lengthy operations
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        });
    });
});
```

Also, if you choose to work with selectors - make sure your UIActivityIndicatorView is declared outside the scope of the method.

Comment: You say ".. should never call detachNewThreadSelector with a selector that performs UI related tasks."but you use dispatch_get_main_queue(). Aren't they the same?

Comment: No - the detachNewThreadSelector creates a thread that runs the task in the background. Using GCD's dispatch_get_main_queue ensures that the code runs on the main thread.

Comment: i tryed your code, and it's the same result as i got before, but now main thread isn't blocked, so activity indicator doesn't go away

Comment: Try setting the activityIndicator's hidesWhenStopped property to YES

Comment: Same result, and also uploading operations are performing much more longer, than without dispatch_async(...)

Comment: You can try changing DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT to DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH. Also, make sure that the reference you have to the activity indicator is valid (not nil).

Comment: @Stavash I shall take a look at documentations about GCD, i was't sure but i used to think dispatch_get_main_queue() uses the main thread hence there will be no difference if i use it without multithreading..thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void) startSpinner
{
    self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [spinner setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2.0, self.view.frame.size.height/2.0)];
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];
}


- (void)startSync
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startSpinner) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

    // computations 

    [self.spinner performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    self.spinner = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens become you declare local variable spinner inside startSpinner method.

When you call self.spinner, it does not affect the local variable spinner you declared inside startSpinner method. You have 2 separate variable with same name.

You have to declare

spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];